# Set image width on mobile to be size of window

Tags: css, image, width

Is the only way to ensure that an image properly takes up the width on a mobile device, this:

```
if ($(window).width() < $("#entry img").width()) 
{
    $("#entry img").width($(window).width());
}
```

Like is there no better way in css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use media queries to check device width in CSS, and then just override your image width to 100% within the query for mobile widths:

MDN has the usual exhaustive documentation on how to go about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```

This means that devices with a screen width of less than 600px will be served the CSS within the query... which may be an override of your default image styling. You can tweak the query width to your choosing and stack additional query blocks in your CSS to set up unique styling for tablet resolutions, etc.